# Duplicated dex but whithout duplicated .jar

Tags: java, android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to build my application with cordova and I get this error:

```
    Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes;
    Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/annotation/AnimatorRes;
    Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/annotation/AnyRes;
    Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/annotation/ArrayRes;
    Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/annotation/AttrRes;
    Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/annotation/BoolRes;
    Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/annotation/ColorRes;
    Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/annotation/DimenRes;
    Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/annotation/DrawableRes;
```

This is my `grade androidDependecies`

```
armv7Debug
+--- LOCAL: gcm.jar
+--- me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.2
+--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1
|    \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-23.1.1.jar
+--- org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:15.44.384.13
+--- android:CordovaLib:unspecified:debug
\--- android.phonegap-facebook-plugin:FacebookLib:unspecified:debug
     +--- LOCAL: android-support-v4.jar
     +--- LOCAL: bolts-android-1.1.2.jar
     \--- android:CordovaLib:unspecified:debug
```

It suggest that **android.phonegap-facebook-plugin:FacebookLib** needs android-support-v4.jar that is already called and so it get duplicated.

My problem is that I only have one **android-support-v4.jar** in my project folders under FacebookLib\libs and that's the only one I can found.

In my build.gradle I commented `compile "com.android.support:support-v4:+"` and when I build with Android Studio it works but when instead i do `ionic build android` my changes get overwritten

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open build.gradle (Module Android) in Android Studio and put this lines in the head:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    all*.exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services'
}
```

This lines helped me and prevents the build for including several modules twice.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your build.gradle file :

```
lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
 }
```

AND if using Cordova:

```
cordova plugin remove android.support.v4
```

For compiling an Android Studio app without loosing anything, just use the gradlew already present in the app folder. The method you are using doesn't take advantage of what you have already done in setting up those files. I suggest using this:

```
./gradlew build
```

Keep in mind that this is just gradle and works for other gradle commands like:

```
./gradlew clean
```

Comment: I commented `compile "com.android.support:support-v4:+"` and then i did your `gradlew build`.. It finished successfully but then as soon as i did a `ionic build android` it was overwritten again

Comment: In your build.gralde file, add this line: lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}       This should fix this for you!

Comment: V4 support lib is also in Cordova natively. You likely need to perform cordova plugin remove android.support.v4

Comment: I get `Plugin "android.support.v4" is not present in the project`

Comment: Have you looked at this post - they seem to have the exact same issue: https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/issues/992